# Why can't jq's slurp handle a combination of here-strings and other files?

Tags: bash, unix, jq

I want to merge some json in a file with some json generated at runtime. jq seems to have no difficulty if all the files passed to it are here-strings, or files in the system. But if I try to mix the file types it seems the here-strings are ignored, see snippet below:

Two normal files:

```
bash-4.2# echo '{"key":0}' > zero
bash-4.2# echo '{"key":1}' > one
bash-4.2# jq --slurp add zero one
{
  "key": 1
}
```

**Normal file and here-string (only normal file appears in result!):**

```
bash-4.2# jq --slurp add zero <<< '{"key":1}'
{
  "key": 0
}
```

**Here-string first, then normal file (only normal file appears in result!):**

```
bash-4.2# jq --slurp add <<< '{"key":0,"anotherkey":2}' one
{
  "key": 1
}
```

Single here-string (works fine):

```
bash-4.2# jq --slurp add <<< '{"key":0}'
{
  "key": 0
}
```

<s>Two here-strings (works fine):</s> EDIT: Output is misleading, something else is going on here.

```
bash-4.2# jq --slurp add <<< '{"key":0}' <<< '{"key":1}'
{
  "key": 1
}
```

My suspicion is that jq works just fine and I am ignorant of how bash resolves the here-strings. But, how would I debug this to improve my understanding?

Note: A very easy workaround would be to evaluate my runtime json and produce a file, then merge the two files as above. I really want to know why the bold examples above don't produce what I would expect.

Comment: Note that a herestring is an instruction to the shell on how to configure stdin. You can only have one stdin, and ordering wrt. where you put the herestring amongst command line arguments doesn't change how it's processed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The here-string construct simply redirects standard input. You will separately need to tell `jq` to *read* standard input if you call it in a way where it receives file name arguments. The *de facto* standard way to do that is to specify `-` as the input (pseudo-) filename.

I believe one of your test cases didn't actually work, and just looked like it did because the input data was constructed so as to be a no-op.

Comment: For clarity, the test case that didn't actually work is the last one with two here-strings. Unless prefixed with a file descriptor other than 0, the `<<<` operator redirects standard input; and if a command contains multiple redirections applied to the standard input, only the rightmost one takes effect. So, JQ receives `{"key":1}`, puts it into an array, and extracts it back; it never reads `{"key":0}`.

Comment: This helped me to investigate a little further. It looks like jq is able to read from stdin correctly if no other positional arguments are passed, which misled me.

Answer (score 4):

After reading through the comments this is my understanding:

`<<<` is evaluated by the shell first and redirects stdin. If `jq` receives no positional arguments after the filter, it reads from stdin. Therefore all these statements are equivalent:

```
echo "{}" | jq --slurp add
<<< {} jq --slurp add
jq <<< {} --slurp add
jq --slurp <<< {} add
jq --slurp add <<< {}
```

If `jq` does receive positional arguments after the filter, it interprets them as filenames. It adheres to the convention of treating `-` as stdin.

```
bash-4.2# echo '{"one":1,"two":1}' > first
bash-4.2# echo '{"three":3}' > third
bash-4.2# jq --slurp add first - third <<< '{"two":2}'
{
  "one": 1,
  "two": 2,
  "three": 3
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One idea would be to use process substitution which, in essence, provides `jq` with a (temp) file descriptor it can work with.

Using `awk` to demonstrate the file descriptor idea:

```
$ awk '{print FILENAME}' <(echo 'abc')
/dev/fd/63
```

Demonstrating with a few of your examples:

```
$ jq --slurp add zero <(echo '{"key":1}')
{
  "key": 1
}

$ jq --slurp add zero <(echo '{"keyx":1}')
{
  "key": 0,
  "keyx": 1
}

$ jq --slurp add <(echo '{"key":0,"anotherkey":2}') one
{
  "key": 1,
  "anotherkey": 2
}

$ jq --slurp add <(echo '{"key":0}') <(echo '{"key":1}')
{
  "key": 1
}

$ jq --slurp add <(echo '{"key":0}') <(echo '{"keyx":1}')
{
  "key": 0,
  "keyx": 1
}
```